# problem with updating parent component state via rendered function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the parent APP.js :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './components/header';
import Cards from './components/cards';
import Footer from './components/footer';
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    to_favorite: [],
  };


  toFav = data => {
    this.setState(function(prevState, props) {
      if (prevState.to_favorite !== data) {
      if (prevState.to_favorite.includes(data) === false) {
        return {to_favorite: data};
      }
      }
    });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header data={this.state.to_favorite} />
        <div className="cards-body">
          <Cards toFav={this.toFav} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The child component which the function triggered from:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Card from './card';

class Cards extends Component {
  state = {
    books: [
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'HTTP: The Definitive Guide',
        author: 'David Gourley',
        cover: 'http',
        price: '46,61',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        title: 'JavaScript: The Definitive Guide',
        author: 'David Flanagan',
        cover: 'js',
        price: '35,52',
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        title:
          'The TCP/IP Guide: A Comprehensive, Illustrated Internet Protocols Reference',
        author: 'Charles M.Kozierok',
        cover: 'tcp_ip',
        price: '54,50',
      },
      {
        id: '4',
        title:
          'Node.js 8 the Right Way: Practical, Server-Side JavaSCript The Scales',
        author: 'Jim Wilson',
        cover: 'nodejs',
        price: '28,21',
      },
    ],
    favorite: [],
    bag: [],
  };

  isaFav = data => {
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
      this.setState({favorite: [...this.state.favorite, data]});
    } else {
      this.setState({
        favorite: this.state.favorite.filter(fav => fav.id != data[0]),
      });
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cards" tofav={this.props.toFav(this.state.favorite)}>
        {this.state.books.map(book => (
          <Card isaFav={this.isaFav} bookInfos={book} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cards;
```

I'm trying to move data between sibling components, without redux  just with toggled function that brings data from child component (Cards). at this point everything is cool I can do console.log for data and it shows well. the problem comes when I try to set state to the parent component that include the toggled function, that function is triggering many times. at the end it shows me this error.

"react-dom.development.js:55 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops."

I tried componenDidUpdate() but it can't stop that function from triggering.

is there any solution for that? and is it the appropriate way to work with states in react?

Comment: show your card component. if it is long show exactly where you trigger the toFav method?

Comment: the post has been updated ;)